# Most effective way to populate database with data?

Tags: java, spring-boot, performance-testing, k6

Hi I need to run some performance tests of my spring boot batch jobs.  I am looking for the most effective way to set the data into the mongo database.  The data is encrypted in the service, so I cant directly load the data via mongo.  I want to load up 1million plus records.  Should I be looking to use a load testing tool such as K6, or would it make more sense to set up a threadpool executor and write some java to get the data in??

Comment: YCSB should be able to load Mongo with random data. I'm not sure how that would test your own app, though

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I need my service to encrypt the data before it is loaded. The test if basically a Manual cron job run to see how long it takes to produce a batch file.

Comment: Does your service expose a rest api to upload data? If not I think your only option would be a thread pool, like you say

Comment: Yes it does, was thinking I could use something like k6 or jmeter to get the data in?

Comment: I'm not familiar with k6, but seems like a reasonable approach to me. Have you tried it yet?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to measure the time required to insert 1M of records into the database you can consider the following options:

1. If it is possible to use Java code consider wrapping it into a microbenchmark test harness like [JMH](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-performance/jmh.html), this way you will get some performance metrics which are not provided by [future tasks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html) per se.
2. Assuming you're considering using k6 and it [doesn't support anything but HTTP](https://docs.k6.io/docs/protocols) it seems your application exposes a HTTP interface, and assuming the system under test is a Spring Boot application it makes more sense to go for a Java-based load testing tool, this way you will be able to use the same infrastructure for the load tests as for the system under test. Moreover [k6 can be executed only on one machine](https://github.com/loadimpact/k6/issues/140) and I believe distributed clustered mode is a must have for a good load testing tool just in case if you will need to scale your load test. The most advanced free and open source load testing tools which are Java/JVM based are:

   - [The Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/)
   - [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)
   - [Gatling](https://gatling.io/)

Check out [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use/) article to learn more about main features of the above solutions.